# MSBuild: Output properties from imported projects

Tags: msbuild

Let's say I have a `build.proj` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
         DefaultTargets="AfterBuild"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <CustomAfterMicrosoftCSharpTargets>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Common.Build.targets</CustomAfterMicrosoftCSharpTargets>
        <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
        <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
        <ProjectProperties>
            Configuration=$(Configuration);
            Platform=$(Platform);
            CustomAfterMicrosoftCSharpTargets=$(CustomAfterMicrosoftCSharpTargets);
        </ProjectProperties>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectToBuild Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)src\Proj\MyApp.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild Targets="Build"
                 Projects="@(ProjectToBuild)"
                 Properties="$(ProjectProperties)" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOn="Build">
        <Message Text="ChildProperty: $(ChildProperty)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

In `Common.Build.targets`, I have a `Target` that creates a property:

```
<Target Name="DoSomethingUseful">
    <!-- Do something useful -->
    <CreateProperty Value="SomeComputedThingy">
        <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="ChildProperty"/>
    </CreateProperty>
</Target>
```

Now if I build `build.proj`, I do not see the value of `ChildProperty` in the message. The output is blank: `ChildProperty:`.

I was under the impression that any output for a target is merged back to global context after its execution. But it seems that it only applies to anything *within* that target file.

How do I make `ChildProperty` bubble up to the parent `build.proj`?

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `<MSBuild>` task on dependent projects, read `TargetOutputs` output parameter of the task. See example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx):

```
<Target Name="BuildOtherProjects">
    <MSBuild
        Projects="@(ProjectReferences)"
        Targets="Build">
        <Output
            TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"
            ItemName="AssembliesBuiltByChildProjects" />
    </MSBuild>
</Target>
```

You will also need to ensure the target you are calling in dependent projects correctly populates `Returns` or `Output` parameter (`Returns` takes precedence if used). E.g.:

```
<Target Name="MyTarget" Inputs="..." Outputs="..." Returns="$(MyOutputValue)">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <MyOutputValue>set it here</MyOutputValue>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work. `AssembliesBuiltByChildProjects` is empty. And this explains why: `Only the outputs from the targets that were specified are returned, not any outputs that may exist on targets that those targets depend on.`

Comment: @Mrchief, why would you expect it to be otherwise? When you call a function in C# that returns some object, you don't see the return be some sort of aggregate of everything that was called by the function. Of course, calling a function is not a direct analogy of invoking a target in MSBuild, but it is somewhat close. When you need output of specific target, invoke it using MSBuild task or CallTarget task and use the output value.

Comment: I'm not expecting that. My question is specifically about bubbling up a property created by one of the child targets. I'm Ok with creating a property in the global scope, question is - how? A child function can always write a global variable, yes? And let's not get into the global variable is evil debate. All I want is to bubble up a property.